# List rows ordered by disk usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL server table that has grown to 100GB size for one customer. On average this table occupies 1-5 GB.

We would like to list rows in this table ordered by disk usage to do a clean up.

How can this be done?

Comment: As per my understanding , u want to delete the rows which are occupying more space, i can suggest one way , where u aggregate all columns of one row and get the  length of the result and u can order by the length and delete those rows from top
[or]
while inserting itself , have partitions on the length of the row[columns together], i haven't tried with large data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered on the DBA Stack Exchange [HERE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/how-can-i-get-the-actual-data-size-per-row-in-a-sql-server-table), the query they used was:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @idcol NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @table = '"TABLE NAME"';
SET @idcol = '"TABLE ID"';


SET @sql = 'select '+@idcol+' , (0';
SELECT
    @sql = @sql+' + isnull(datalength(['+name+']), 1)'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table);
SET @sql = @sql+') as rowsize from '+@table+' order by rowsize desc';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC (@sql);
```

Just add in the table name and the id for the customer

Answer (score 0):

Query the table and order by DATALENGTH() of all the columns concatenated:

`ORDER BY DATALENGTH(Column1) + DATALENGTH(Column2) + DATALENGTH(...)`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding , u want to delete the rows which are occupying more space, i can suggest one way , where u aggregate all columns of one row and get the length of the result and u can order by the length and delete those rows from top

[or]

while inserting itself , have partitions on the length of the row[columns together], i haven't tried with large data